# Doc2Vec similarity small corpus test

Tags: python, doc2vec

I can't get any reasonable response for a doc2vec simple test of doc similarity for a very small corpus. The same document, or using some unique words, never returns itself or anything close.

There are codes like [this one](https://markroxor.github.io/gensim/static/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.html) where the author could check that:

> greater than 95% of the inferred documents are found to be most similar to itself and about 5% of the time it is mistakenly most similar to another document.

This code below is based on this example from [mishra.thedeepak](https://medium.com/@mishra.thedeepak/doc2vec-simple-implementation-example-df2afbbfbad5)

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec

data = ["I love machine learning Its awesome",
        "I love coding in python",
        "I love building chatbots",
        "they chat amagingly well"]

tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(words=word_tokenize(_d.lower()), tags=[str(i)]) for i, _d in enumerate(data)]

max_epochs = 100
vec_size = 20
alpha = 0.025

model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=vec_size,
                alpha=alpha, 
                min_alpha=0.00025,
                min_count=1,
                dm=1)

model.build_vocab(tagged_data)

for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    model.train(tagged_data, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)
    model.alpha -= 0.0002
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha

# Now testing the same doc, trying to find similarity to itself:

test_data = word_tokenize("I love coding in python".lower())
v1 = model.infer_vector(test_data)
similar_doc = model.docvecs.most_similar([v1], topn=len(model.docvecs))

# The high score
print("similar_doc", similar_doc)
print(data[int(similar_doc[0][0])])
```

An identical document, yet it returns:

```
similar_doc [('3', 0.44355273246765137), ('2', 0.4423074722290039), ('0', 0.4166065454483032), ('1', 0.3881992995738983)]
they chat amagingly well
```

Tried many variations like the phrase "building chatbots" or even the word "python" which returns

```
similar_doc [('0', -0.09640596807003021), ('3', -0.16155308485031128), ('1', -0.1653675138950348), ('2', -0.1833440363407135)]
I love machine learning. Its awesome.
```

No matter how many times I try, the correct match of the document is so rare that it seems to be the same chance as random.

Is there any way to get better results for doc2vec on simple corpus like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get interesting results from tiny toy-sized datasets from `Doc2Vec` & similar algorithms, which rely on large, subtly-varied training datasets in order to create the 'dense' & meaningful vectors.

In particular, you can't get meaningfu **twenty**-dimensional vectors from a training set that only has **four** contrasting examples! You need many, many more contrasting examples than dimensions, so that the model is gradually nudged into learning a 'compressed' representation of the text – where similar texts are forced to be 'near' each other in the vector space. (If you have more dimensions than examples, there's no 'pressure' at all to force similar texts to share neighborhoods – they can all get wildly different vectors, but the model still has plenty of internal state with which to 'memorize' each text's patterns, with none of the meaningful generalization/learning that happens when trying to model a large number of texts into a smaller number of dimensions.)

Other notes about your usage:

- don't call `train()` multiple times in your own loop, or try to decrement the effective `alpha` yourself: you'll probably do it wrong (as you have here). Just leave the default `alpha`/`min_alpha` in place, specify an `epochs` value when initializing the model, and call `train()` only once: it will do the right number of epochs & manage `alpha` properly.
- `min_count=1` is often a bad idea: rare words with few usage examples usually contribute noise moreso than useful indications of meaning, so the default `min_count=5` (or even higher in larger corpuses) often works better.
- If you specify `epochs` in the class-initialization, as recommended above, then the value you specify will also be used for `infer_vector()`. If you don't, then only the default `epochs=5` will be used, which is often too small (especially when inferring against a model originally trained with more `epochs`. (Values of 10-20 or more are most common in published results.)

Comment: Min-count = 1 would make sense in such a small dataset but you were clear in your explanation. I found so many similar examples with doc2vec and small datasets like this, all not working, that I thought I was doing something wrong. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tutorial you'd based your code on - I left a comment there to warn other readers that it includes some buggy practices and is unlikely to work.